# How to implement own thread-safe shared pointer in C++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, pointers

I need to make own simple thread-safe shared pointer class for embedded devices. 
I made counting master pointer and handle as described in Jeff Alger's book (C++ for real programmers). This is my sources:

```
template <class T>
class counting_ptr {
public:
    counting_ptr() : m_pointee(new T), m_counter(0) {}
    counting_ptr(const counting_ptr<T>& sptr) :m_pointee(new T(*(sptr.m_pointee))), m_counter(0)      {}
    ~counting_ptr() {delete m_pointee;}
    counting_ptr<T>& operator=(const counting_ptr<T>& sptr)
    {
        if (this == &sptr) return *this;
        delete m_pointee;
        m_pointee = new T(*(sptr.m_pointee));
        return *this;
    }
    void grab() {m_counter++;}
    void release() 
    {
        if (m_counter > 0) m_counter--;
        if (m_counter <= 0)
            delete this;
    }

    T* operator->() const {return m_pointee;}

private:
    T* m_pointee;
    int m_counter;
};


template <class T>
class shared_ptr {
private:
    counting_ptr<T>* m_pointee;

public:
    shared_ptr() : m_pointee(new counting_ptr<T>()) { m_pointee->grab(); }
    shared_ptr(counting_ptr<T>* a_pointee) : m_pointee(a_ptr) { m_pointee->grab(); }
    shared_ptr(const shared_ptr<T>& a_src) : m_pointee(a_src.m_pointee) {m_pointee->grab(); }
    ~shared_ptr()  { m_pointee->release(); }

    shared_ptr<T>& operator=(const shared_ptr<T>& a_src)
    {
        if (this == &a_src) return *this;
        if (m_pointee == a_src.m_pointee) return *this;
        m_pointee->release();
        m_pointee = a_src.m_pointee;
        m_pointee->grab();
        return *this;
    }
    counting_ptr<T>* operator->() const {return m_pointee;}
};
```

This works fine if it used in one thread. Suppose I have two threads:

```
//thread 1
shared_ptr<T> p = some_global_shared_ptr;
//thread 2
some_global_shared_ptr = another_shared_ptr;
```

This case I can get undefined behaviour if one of threads will be interrupted between memory allocating/deallocating and counter changing. Of course I can enclose shared_ptr::release() into critical section so deletion of the pointer can be made safety. But what can I do with copy constructor? It is possible that constructor will be interrupted during m_pointee construction by another thread which will delete this m_pointee.
The only way I see to make shared_ptr assignement thread-safe is to enclose the assignment (or creation) into critical section. But this must be done in "user code". In other words user of shared_ptr class must take care about safety. 
Is it possible to change this realization somehow to make the shared_ptr class thread safe?

=== EDIT ===

After some investigations (thanks to Jonathan) I realized that my `shared_ptr` has three unsafe places:

- Unatomic counter changing
- Unatomic assignment operator (source object can be deleted during copying)
- shared_ptr copy constructor (very similar to previous case)

First two cases could be easily fixed by adding crtical sections. But I can't realize how to add critical section into copy constructor? Copy of `a_src.m_pointee` created before any other code in the constructor executed and can be deleted before calling `grab`. As Jonathan said in his comment it is very difficult to fix this problem. 
I made such test:

```
typedef shared_ptr<....> Ptr;
Ptr p1, p2;

//thread 1
while (true)
{
    Ptr p;
    p2 = p;
}

//thread 2
while (!stop)
{
    p1 = p2;
    Ptr P(p2);
}
```

Of course, it crashed. But I have tried to use std::shared_ptr in VS 2013 C++. And it works!
So it is possible to make thread-safe copy constructor for `shared_ptr`. But stl sources too difficult for me and I don't understand how they did the trick. Please anyone explain me how it works in STL?

=== EDIT 2 ===

I am sorry, but the test for std::shared_ptr was made wrong. It doesn't pass too exactly as boost::shared_ptr does. Sometimes copy constructor fails to make a copy because source was deleted during copying. In this case empty pointer will be created.

Comment: Look at the implementation of `std::shared_ptr` and `boost::shared_ptr`.

Comment: your counting must be atomic!

Comment: Are you familiar with the new `atomic` types in C++11?

Comment: @sjdowling, `shared_ptr` does **not** support reading and writing from the same instance without synchonrization. The accesses on `some_global_shared_ptr` would be undefined behaviour with `std::shared_ptr` or `boost::shared_ptr`. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm#ThreadSafety

Comment: just as a hint: try to avoid sharing data between different threads it's a performance killer. See also: https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/people/paulmck/perfbook/perfbook.html

Comment: Why have you bothered to define a copy constructor and assignment operator for `counting_ptr` when it should never get copied?

Comment: I'd look into getting a different book.  The implementation above isn't correct, even in a single threaded environment.

Comment: "*It is possible that constructor will be interrupted during m_pointee construction by another thread which will delete this m_pointee.*" No, since the thing you're copying holds a reference to the pointee, so its reference count cannot drop to zero.

Comment: @David, it **is** possible. Assume that pointer p2 is a single pointer to some data. One thread started executing command `Ptr p(p2)`. This is a copy constructor. And just after `m_pointee` item will be copied but before incrementing the counter, this thread could be interrupted with another thread executing `p2 = p1`. p2 still has reference counter equal to 1 so it's data will be destroyed and after that p2 will be switched to data block from p1. Now return to first thread and call `grab()` from constructor's body. **Boom**.

Comment: @OlegG. Right, but you can't make behavior predictable in that case anyway -- the race is inherent in the calling sequence. So it has to be the responsibility of callers not to do that.

Comment: @David, right! So an answer to my initial question is NO. It is impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is hard to get right, I would seriously consider whether you actually need to support concurrent reads and writes of a single object (`boost::shared_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr` do **not** support that unless all accesses are done through the `atomic_xxx()` functions that are overloaded for `shared_ptr` and which typically acquire a lock).

For a start you would need to change `shared_ptr<T>::m_pointee` to `atomic<counting_ptr<T>*>` so that you can store a new value in it atomically. `counting_ptr<T>::m_counter` would need to be `atomic<int>` so the ref-count updates can be done atomically.

Your assignment operator is a big problem, you would need to *at least* re-order the operations so you increase the ref-count first, and avoid [time of check to time of use](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_of_check_to_time_of_use) bugs, something like this (not even compiled, let alone tested):

```
shared_ptr<T>& operator=(const shared_ptr<T>& a_src)
{
    counter_ptr<T>* new_ptr = a_src.m_pointee.load();
    new_ptr->grab();
    counter_ptr<T>* old_ptr = m_pointee.exchange(new_ptr);
    old_ptr->release();
    return *this;
}
```

This form is safe against self-assignment (it just increases the ref-count then decreases it again if the two objects share the same pointee). It's still **not** safe against `a_src` changing while you try to copy it. Consider the case where `a_src.m_pointee->m_counter == 1` initially. The current thread could call `load()` to get the other object's pointer, then a second thread could call `release()` on that pointer, which would `delete` it, making the `grab()` call undefined behaviour because it accesses an object that has been destroyed and memory that has been deallocated. Fixing that requires a pretty major redesign and maybe atomic operations that can operate on two words at once.

Getting this right is possible but is **hard** and you should really reconsider whether it's necessary, or if the code using it can just avoid modifying objects while other threads are reading them, except while the user has locked a mutex or other form of manual synchronisation.

Comment: Thank you very much! It became much clear now. You are right that it will be better to avoid such assignment at all. But I guessed if there exist a _simple_ way to make it thread safe. You proove that it is not so simple. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Jonathan, it seems that things not so bad as you said. Of course, grab counter **must** be atomic. But assignment operator may be not so unsafe. If all works fine, `a_src.m_pointee->m_counter` can be 1 if this `a_src` used in curent thread only (I suppose that there are no any variables shared between threads). But if it used in this (current) thread only it can't be deleted by other thread during assignment operator execution. If another thread has own copy of `shared_ptr` object with same `m_pointee` value than `m_pointee->counter >= 2` and it can't be deleted unexpectedly again.

Comment: _"I suppose that there are no any variables shared between threads"_ Oh well in that case you're asking a different question. Your original question included changes to variables shared between threads, such as `some_global_shared_ptr`

Comment: Yes, I am sorry. In fact I really need to use one `m_pointee` object in defferent threads. But `shared_ptr` instances for that objects must be unique for every thread. But the problem still here: how one thread (which created m_pointee initially) can give it to another thread? One solution is to use global variable and another - some kind of OS interprocess communication like messageboxes. To use global vriables it will be enough to enclose `grab`, `release` and assignment operator into critical section, am I right?

Comment: It's easy to make a shared ptr that can be copied by multiple threads at once, as long as you can ensure that the object being copied is not being modified concurrently with the copies.

Answer (score 0):

After some investigations I can conclude that it is impossible to make thread-safe shared_ptr class where thread-safety understood as follow:

```
//thread 1
shared_ptr<T> p = some_global_shared_ptr;
//thread 2
some_global_shared_ptr = another_shared_ptr;
```

This example doesn't guarantees that `p` in first thread will point to old or new value of `some_global_shared_ptr`. In general this example leads to undefined behavior. The only way to make the example safety is to wrap both operators into critical sections or mutial exclusions.

The main problem caused by copy constructor of `shared_ptr` class. Other problems could be solved using critical sections inside `shared_ptr` methods.

Answer (score 0):

Just inherit your class from CmyLock and you can make everything thread safe. 
I use this class already many years in all my code, usually combined with class CmyThread, which creates a thread that has a very safe mutex. Maybe my answer is a little late, but above answers are not good practice.

```
/** Constructor */
CmyLock::CmyLock()
{
    (void) pthread_mutexattr_init( &m_attr);
    pthread_mutexattr_settype( &m_attr, PTHREAD_MUTEX_RECURSIVE);
    pthread_mutex_init( &m_mutex, &m_attr);
}

/** Lock the thread for other threads. */
void CmyLock::lock()
{
    pthread_mutex_lock( &m_mutex);
}

/** Unlock the thread for other threads. */
void CmyLock::unlock()
{
    pthread_mutex_unlock( &m_mutex);
}
```

Here also the thread class. Try Please copy CmyLock and CmyThread classes to your project and tell when it's working! Although it's made for Linux, also Windows and Mac should be able to run this.

For the include file:

```
// @brief Class to create a single thread.
class CmyThread : public CmyLock
{
friend void *mythread_interrupt(void *ptr);

public:
    CmyThread();
    virtual ~CmyThread();
    virtual void startWorking() {}
    virtual void stopWorking() {}
    virtual void work();
    virtual void start();
    virtual void stop();
    bool isStopping() { return m_stopThread; }
    bool isRunning() { return m_running && !m_stopThread; }

private:
    virtual void run();

private:
    bool                m_running;      ///< Thread is now running.
    pthread_t           m_thread;       ///< Pointer to thread.
    bool                m_stopThread;   ///< Indicate to stop thread.
};
```

The C++ file:

```
/** @brief Interrupt handler.
 *  @param ptr [in] SELF pointer for the instance.
 */
void *mythread_interrupt(void *ptr)
{
    CmyThread *irq =
            static_cast<CmyThread*> (ptr);
    if (irq != NULL)
    {
        irq->run();
    }
    return NULL;
}
/** Constructor new thread. */
CmyThread::CmyThread()
: m_running( false)
, m_thread( 0)
, m_stopThread( false)
{
}

/** Start thread. */
void CmyThread::start()
{
    m_running =true;
    m_stopThread =false;
    pthread_attr_t attr;
    pthread_attr_init(&attr);
    pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);
    int stack_size =8192*1024;
    pthread_attr_setstacksize(&attr, stack_size);
    pthread_create(&m_thread, &attr, mythread_interrupt, (void*) this);
}

/** Thread function running. */
void CmyThread::run()
{
    startWorking();
    while (m_running && m_stopThread==false)
    {
        work();
    }
    m_running =false;
    stopWorking();
    pthread_exit(0);
}

/** Function to override for a thread. */
virtual void CmyThread::work()
{
    delay(5000);
}
```

For example, here a simplistic example to store and retrieve 1000 data:

```
    class a : public CmyLock
    {
        set_safe(int *data)
        {
            lock();
            fileContent =std::make_shared<string>(data); 
            unlock();
        }

        get_safe(char *data)
        {
            lock();
            strcpy( data, fileContent->c_str());
            unlock();
        }
        std::shared_ptr<string> fileContent;
    };
```